# fetch failed err -3008 | Next js server actions

Tags: next.js, fetch, fetch-api, nextjs-image

[Screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxLDm.png)
How do i solve this error. Everything worked before that point
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKZAXFjxlJI is video reference( stop at 20 mins ).
Everything which he did worked for me aswell but not with that image

To diplay the anime image in the website

Comment: you should use ` `your code` ` instead of  ' your code ' in image src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Backticks (`) instead of single quote (') when creates a string replacing the `${expression}`.

```
<Image
src={`https://shikimori.one${anime.image.original}`}
{...rest}
/>
```

For more information here [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)